# IPsec SAref does not work with L2TP kernel mode yet

Tags: vpn, vps

xl2tpd -D echo:

```
xl2tpd[7681]: Enabling IPsec SAref processing for L2TP transport mode SAs
xl2tpd[7681]: IPsec SAref does not work with L2TP kernel mode yet, enabling forceuserspace=yes
xl2tpd[7681]: init_network: Unable to bind socket: Address already in use. Terminating.
```

what should i do next? i want to build a vpn server on my vps.

Answer (score -2):

just let xl2tpd run in userspace, it will be slower but it works for me

FYI - i don't feel it slow.

source: my daemon.log

```
Oct  4 18:29:39 tk xl2tpd[22238]: Enabling IPsec SAref processing for L2TP transport mode SAs
Oct  4 18:29:39 tk xl2tpd[22238]: IPsec SAref does not work with L2TP kernel mode yet, enabling forceuserspace=yes
Oct  4 18:29:39 tk xl2tpd[22238]: setsockopt recvref[30]: Protocol not available
Oct  4 18:29:39 tk xl2tpd[22238]: This binary does not support kernel L2TP.
Oct  4 18:29:39 tk xl2tpd[22239]: xl2tpd version xl2tpd-1.3.1 started on tk PID:22239
Oct  4 18:29:39 tk xl2tpd[22239]: Written by Mark Spencer, Copyright (C) 1998, Adtran, Inc.
Oct  4 18:29:39 tk xl2tpd[22239]: Forked by Scott Balmos and David Stipp, (C) 2001
Oct  4 18:29:39 tk xl2tpd[22239]: Inherited by Jeff McAdams, (C) 2002
Oct  4 18:29:39 tk xl2tpd[22239]: Forked again by Xelerance (www.xelerance.com) (C) 2006
Oct  4 18:29:39 tk xl2tpd[22239]: Listening on IP address 0.0.0.0, port 1701
```